# Comparing proportions when samples overlap

Tags: hypothesis-testing, assumptions

I would like to compare the proportion of people using a facility who are female with the proportion of people who live in the area that are female. The goal is to determine if women are over or underrepresented among facility users for some reason.

Since there are many people who both live in the area and use the facility, the samples overlap. Therefore I don't think I meet the independence of samples assumption for a t-test. However, I don't know specifically which people belong to both groups so I can't merely remove them. I don't have individual-level data. All I know is that x% of the 10,000 people who live in the area are female and y% of the 100 facility users are female.

Is there any other way to reliably compare these two proportions and determine if the difference is statistically significant?

I know a similar question was asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/389837/comparing-proportions-from-overlapping-samples), but the answers didn't really suggest how to move forward in a valid way.

Comment: Asked and answered many times: just remove the overlaps from those who live in the area and proceed.  Whether that's valid depends on how you obtained your samples.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not an option because I don't know who belongs to both samples. I don't have individual level data, just aggregated. I will edit my OP to reflect this.